# Put onClick event in <li> to call AJAX

Tags: javascript, html

When I put `onClick` event in `button` element inside `li` element like below to make AJAX:

```
<ul>
<li><button value="orange" onClick="qCat(value)">Orange</button></li> 
<li><button value="apple" onClick="qCat(value)">Apple</button></li>
</ul>
```

It works nicely.

But if I take away `button` to apply event directly to `li` element like below make AJAX:

```
<ul>
<li value="orange" onClick="qCat(value)">Orange</li> 
<li value="apple" onClick="qCat(value)">Apple</li>
</ul>
```

It won't work. Anything wrong with my code? Pls advice. Thanks.

Comment: Try to stay away from inline Javascript, it's better practice to use `document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', myFunction)`

Comment: Are you using a list as an option selector? You could use `<select>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select which natively supports `onchange` event and `value` property

Comment: r u sure? I check W3school it says: The "value" attribute was deprecated in HTML 4.01, but IS supported in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `value` attribute of an `li` element is supposed to be a **number**.
 Furthermore it is **only supported for Ordered Lists** (`ol`).

The values can even be auto-incrementing by setting the first value to e.g. 100 and then the rest will follow.

If I test your code then the function qCat() receives a 0 (*zero*) parameter which is consistent with the above.

For additional info see here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the argument passed to your function (thanks to @epascarello for pointing that out).  See the code below.

```js
function qCat(val) {
  console.log(val.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li value="orange" onClick="qCat(this)">Orange</li> 
<li value="apple" onClick="qCat(this)">Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Guessing you did not try and run the button code and see what is different.

Answer (score 0):

The **value** attribute sets the value of a list item. The following list items will increment from that number.

The value **must be a number** and can only be used in ordered lists

In order to get the expected result use **data-*** (a HTML global attribute)

```js
qCat = function(elm){
  val = elm.getAttribute('data-value');
  alert(val);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-value="orange" onClick="qCat(this)">Orange</li> 
  <li data-value="apple" onClick="qCat(this)">Apple</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function First(){
        alert('it is the first option');
    }

    function Second(){
        alert('it is the second option');
    }
     function General(){
        alert('it is a shared option');
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick=First();>First option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"onclick=Second();>Second option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"onclick=General();>Third option</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"onclick=General();>Forth option</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into this updated code.

```js
function qCat(event){
debugger;
  console.log($(event.target).attr('value'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li value="orange" onClick="qCat(event)">Orange</li> 
<li value="apple" onClick="qCat(event)">Apple</li>
</ul>
```